# EXTJS XTemplate

Tags: extjs

I have a method as follows :

```
createTip : function() {
    var eventTip = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl if="EventType == \'ONE\'">', 
        '<p> This is event one </p>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<tpl if="EventType == \'Two\'">', 
          return null;
        '</tpl>' 
    );

    return eventTip;

}
```

What I want to do is if the EventType is 'TWO', to make the method return null. Is this possible?

As in something like the code above. I know this is not possible but is there anyway of doing so. Pretty much if the EventType is two, I don't want a xtemplate to be created.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean return null? the XTemplate is compiled and applied data to generate string. If you have access to data in your function and want to return null when a data point matches your value - just do that.

Comment: I changed the code above to show you what I mean. I know this is not possible but is there anyway of doing so. Pretty much if the EventType is two, I don't want a xtemplate to be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
applyDataToMyTemplate: function(data){
  if (data.EventType === 'Two'){
    return null; //or '', or false, or whatever you need
  } else {
     return this.createTip().apply(data); //or some such hackery
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where do you use this function? When is it called? And what is the data here? Thanks

Comment: where does createTip get called? same place. data is also the same as passed into the template.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be needing something other than an XTemplate if you really need to return null.  I'm not aware of any use case for doing that with a template, and it should break most of the widgets if the xtemplate returns something other than the html fragment that it's supposed to.  If you just need it not to show anything when EventType is Two then you can use the template functions to adjust your generated HTML or do pretty much anything else you want to by building a string.  Doing this discards the benefits of creating partial dom elements ahead of time to be reused that the XTemplate is supposed to provide though:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
    '{[this.buildTemplate(values)]}',
    {
        buildTemplate: function (values) {
            if (values.EventType === "One") {
                return "<p> This is event one </p>";
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
)
```